# How do dielectric molecules in a liquid phase align when polarized?

Tags: electrons, materials, solvents, liquid-crystals

As seen in the diagram, when a dielectric material becomes electrically polarized, the molecules align themselves in a manner where the respective charges are parallel to each other horizontally.

However, this diagram shows a solid dielectric, and are fixed in place. How would a liquid dielectric’s molecule align themselves are they are in motion and rotate? Would a strong enough field fixate them as in the diagram below?[image]

Comment: Perhaps look at “Dielectric spectroscopy” in wikipedia. One of the regimes involves seeing how those dipoles dance to the tune of the alternating electric field.

Comment: The molecules drawn in the second diagram are not necessarily fixed. They can move, and they will move if the material is liquid and if the field is maintained. But their polarization will be roughly maintained.